# Assigning an id to a Style Element (v5) in Elm

Tags: html, elm

Is there a way to assign an id to an Element? I would like to use the toBottom function in the elm-lang/dom library in order to autoscroll a chat window but I need an id for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import Html.Attributes as Attr exposing (id)
```

and in the element attribute, include `htmlAttribute`

```
el [htmlAttribute (Attr.id "your id")] (text "Sample Text")
```

`htmlAttribute` can be used also for other HTML attributes such as `property'

Comment: "*in the element attribute, include htmlAttribute*" Where does `htmlAttribute` come from?

Comment: It's exposed by Element. https://github.com/mdgriffith/stylish-elephants/blob/master/src/Element.elm

Comment: For me it worked with `div [ Attr.id "your id"]` (I'm using div and not el)